# jQuery's .html() does not return the value of an input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I want to get value of hidden element named "login" on `http://ts1.travian.ro/`'s login page, in order to create a fake login for my Chrome extension.

I would like to do it without jQuery if possible. If not here is my not working example:

```
var url = 'http://ts1.travian.ro/';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        loginValue = $(data).find('input[name=login]').html();
        console.log(loginValue);
    },
});
```

I expected to see the login name in the console, but nothing appeared. How can I solve it?

Comment: And what happens then.? Are you getting any errors

Comment: Didn`t get any value ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `$("element").val()` method.

```
var url = 'http://ts1.travian.ro/';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        loginValue = $(data).find('input[name=login]').val();
        console.log(loginValue);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `html()` method (which wraps the `innerHTML` DOM property) returns the HTML source for the elements inside the current element.
`<input>` cannot have children, so this always returns an empty string.

You want `.val()` (which wraps the `value` DOM property), which returns the current value of an input element.

Comment: @smotru: There is no `value()` function.  jQuery has a function called `val`; native DOM objects have a _property_ called `value`.  You need to learn the DOM.